# Normalization of affine curves in singular surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, singularity-theory, normalization

Let $X$ be a normal, isolated surface singularity with $x_0 \in X$ the unique singularity. Let $C \subset X$ be a hyperplane section i.e., defined by a single equation. Denote by $n:\widetilde{C} \to C$ the normalization of $C$.
Note that, given a set of $n$ sections $(f_1,...,f_n)$ of $n_*\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{C}}$, generatinf it as an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, there is a natural surjective morphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules: $$\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n} \to n_*\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{C}}$$ defined by the sections $f_i$.  Then, the injective $\mathcal{O}_X$-module morphism $\mathcal{O}_C \to n_*\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{C}}$ induces a natural morphism 
$\phi:\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n}$. Under what conditions on $C$ or $X$ and sections $(f_1,...,f_n)$ can we say that the cokernel of the corresponding morphism $\phi$ is $\mathcal{O}_X$-(locally) free? I think this is possible if $C$ does not contain the singular point $x_0$. I am interested in an "if and only if" condition. If necessary, assume that $X$ is a Gorenstein singularity.

Comment: The `natural' morphism $\phi$ is not clear. It is a lift of a section, which is anything but natural.